# Find the order of a function

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity, logarithm, inequality

What is the lowest order of the following function as `n` tends to infinity?
[image]

where `a>1` and `0<p<1`.

**My answer:** Since `ln(1+x) <= x`,

[image]

Therefore, `f(n) = O(a^n)`. I am sure this is not a tight bound. I might be able to use [image] to obtain a tighter bound, but I don't think it will improve the order. Any idea? Please let me know anything you think may be helpful.

Comment: If a<1, then f(n)<0. Maybe you mean a>1 rather than a>0?

Comment: @sds right. thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Please move this question to [Math.SE] or [cstheory.SE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: `O(n^2)`.

Proof:

```
f(n) = sum(i,log(pa^i+(1-p)))
     = sum(i,log(p*a^i(1+(1-p)/(pa^i))))
     =< sum(i,i*log(a)) + sum(i,log(p)) + sum(i,(1-p)/(pa^i))
     =< n*(n+1)*log(a)/2 + n*log(p) + (1-p)/p * 1/(1-1/a)
```

[image]

This estimate is optimal because all inequalities are actually [asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) equivalences.

Note that this is *much* smaller than your exponential estimate.

Comment: That is great! How did you find it?

Comment: @Sus20200: wdym?

Comment: I meant I am surprised.

Comment: Is that optimal? can we show no smaller order can be obtained?

Comment: It's optimal because all inequalities are actually asymptotic equivalences.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, you can use this http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php to produce images for each formula using latex and embed it here.